# why is this function causing the website to refreshe nonstop?

Tags: javascript, html

for some reason when this function is in the code, not even being called, just in the code, the website is constantly refreshing. this function is only called when the button is pressed.

function:

```
var typeofwork = ""
var location = ""
var pay = ""
var timeframe = ""
var email = ""
var phone = ""
var description = ""
var specialrequirements = ""

const list_job_form = [typeofwork , location , pay , timeframe , email , phone , description , specialrequirements];

var list_job_form_filled = true

function list_job_submit() {
  typeofwork = document.getElementById("list_job_typeofwork");
  location = document.getElementById("list_job_location");
  pay = document.getElementById("list_job_pay");
  timeframe = document.getElementById("list_job_timeframe");
  email = document.getElementById("list_job_email");
  phone = document.getElementById("list_job_phone");
  description = document.getElementById("list_job_description");
  specialrequirements = document.getElementById("list_job_specialrequirements");
  
  list_job_form = [typeofwork , location , pay , timeframe , email , phone , description , specialrequirements];

  for (item in list_job_form) {
    console.log(item)
    if (list_job_form[item] === "") {
      list_job_form_filled = false;
    }
  }

}
```

button:

```
<button id="job_listing_submit_button" onclick="list_job_submit()">
                  Submit
                </button>
```

Comment: The global variable `location` is the same as `window.location`. Assigning to that reloads the page.

Comment: Don't use global variables that are the same as standard `window` properties.

Comment: Also, `list_job_form[item]` should be `list_job_form[item].value` to get the value of the inputs.